# Make a Div and it's Child Element's an Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this layout in HTML:

```
<div id="front">
    <img id="student_front" src="' . $path . '/images/student_front.jpg"></img>
    <img id="myid_info_photo"></img>
    <div id="myid_info_college">CEIT</div>
    <div id="myid_info_idnumber">101-03043</div>
    <img id="myid_info_signature"></img>
    <div id="myid_info_course">BSCS</div>
    <div id="myid_info_name">Alyssa E. Gono</div>
    <div id="myid_info_barcode"></div>
</div>
```

I want to generate a Jpeg file of what div#front will appear in my screen. How will I do that in Javascript? I have a button that will invoke an action when it is click.

```
function myid_print_id() {
    win = window.open(document.getElementById("student_front").src,"_blank");
    win.onload = function() { 
        win.print(); 
    }
}

$('#myid_print_id').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    myid_print_id();

});
```

`myid_print_id()` function just retrieves the image file. I wanted to retrieve the appearance of my whole div with an id "front".

Comment: can we show your code what you tried so far?

Comment: Try [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the html2canvas js file, then add this:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#front'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      $('#output').append(canvas);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#output {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="front">
  <img id="student_front" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <div id="myid_info_college">CEIT</div>
  <div id="myid_info_idnumber">101-03043</div>
  <div id="myid_info_course">BSCS</div>
  <div id="myid_info_name">Alyssa E. Gono</div>
  <div id="myid_info_barcode">More text</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">CLICK FOR PIC</button>
<br>
<div id="output"></div>
```

You will need to change the image URL to something on the same domain (html2canvas does not load cross domain images).

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnGenerateImage" value="Generate Image" />
</div>


<div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>
        Generated Content</h1>
    <img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $("#btnGenerateImage").on('click', function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

        // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
        // so it can be saved as an image
        document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

    });
```