# Saving html as an image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it so that you can save the HTML generated on my website as an image using javascript instead of the using having to  manually crop the text on the website and save it using a third party tool.

I have tried using the elements of other questions on stack overflow but with no luck can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Javascript does not have any tools to do that, at least not "out of the box". It may be possible to do if you can somehow generate a screenshot of the page, or if you can manage to copy the content into a `<canvas>` element (which can be converted to an image on-the-fly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803262/make-a-div-and-its-child-elements-an-image-in-javascript/28804001#28804001).  You either specify a div or the body of the document as the target you want to convert to an image, then run html2canvas, like so:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#target'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      $('#output').append(canvas);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#output {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

<div id="target">This is the content you want to turn into an image
  <br>Click the button below to see magic happen.</div>
<br>
<br>
<button id="btn">Snap!</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look into `html2canvas`

here example with description
http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link. It uses html canvas to draw the Dom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas